# Python - Contents not printing from Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Noob coder here trying to learn Selenium. I was following a YouTube tutorial by this channel and I have this code which doesn't work for me but works fine when he runs it in the tutorial. Can you please tell me if I have made any mistakes? Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    

serv_obj = Service("C:\chromedriver.exe")    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)    
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")    
print(driver.title)    

search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "s")    
search.send_keys("test")    
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main")))
    print(main.text)

except:

    driver.quit()
```

And this is the error that I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DaTenshi\PycharmProjects\Scraping\new_scrape.py", line 14, in <module>
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  
File "C:\Users\DaTenshi\PycharmProjects\Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 223, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,

  File "C:\Users\DaTenshi\PycharmProjects\Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\Users\DaTenshi\PycharmProjects\Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\DaTenshi\PycharmProjects\Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: unexpected command response



(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)    
Stacktrace:    
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x00E26463+2188387]    
Ordinal0 [0x00DBE461+1762401]    
Ordinal0 [0x00CD3D78+802168]
Ordinal0 [0x00CC7210+750096]
Ordinal0 [0x00CC675A+747354]
Ordinal0 [0x00CC5D3F+744767]
Ordinal0 [0x00CC4C28+740392]
Ordinal0 [0x00CC5228+741928]
Ordinal0 [0x00CCEF2F+782127]
Ordinal0 [0x00CD9FBB+827323]
Ordinal0 [0x00CDD310+840464]
Ordinal0 [0x00CC54F6+742646]
Ordinal0 [0x00CD9BF3+826355]
Ordinal0 [0x00D2CF6D+1167213]
Ordinal0 [0x00D1C5F6+1099254]
Ordinal0 [0x00CF6BE0+945120]
Ordinal0 [0x00CF7AD6+948950]
GetHandleVerifier [0x010C71F2+2712546]
GetHandleVerifier [0x010B886D+2652765]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00EB002A+520730]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00EAEE06+516086]
Ordinal0 [0x00DC468B+1787531]
Ordinal0 [0x00DC8E88+1805960]
Ordinal0 [0x00DC8F75+1806197]
Ordinal0 [0x00DD1DF1+1842673]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76696A14+36]
RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x774AA9FF+143]
RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x774AA9CA+90]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines of code:

```
serv_obj = Service("C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)
```

So here and import these modules:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you so very much for the reply but its showing the same error. I am currently using pycharm if that helps. I have tried similar program with amazon on trying to print the items when I search the term "Guitar" and I have the same error. 

Any idea on what might be wrong? I installed Selenium through the package installer in pycharm. Haven't been able to move forward because of this problem.

Comment: change it **search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)**  therefore **search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)**

or if this line is not needed for anything you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an active bug that was introduced with the Chrome 103. You can track them below -

https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/BroyfA_GXNQ

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this as soon as I get home. Had been really frustrated with this. I have 103 driver and I'll try lower versions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Reviewers: "this is a bug, here is the bug number/link" *is an answer*.